# How to run WSO2 API Manager from source code

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to run the WSO2 API Manager from source code.

I have installed orbit,kernel and platform of version 4.0.0

After installing the platform(mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dproduct=apimgt), what

is the next step to see the API Manger portal in browser

and play around it.

Answer (score 2):

If you built everything successfully go into product/apimgt//modules/distribution/product/target in platform. then you will find the binary distribution as a zip file you can extract this to a place of your choice and run the wso2server.sh( linux) or wso2server.bat( windows) in the bin folder.

Thanks,
Pulasthi

Comment: Pulasthi I dont have any zip file inside the distribution folder. I have product folder, resources folder and pom file.

Comment: Hi, my bad can you please check in the product folder within distribution there should be an folder named target it should contain the zip file

Comment: pulasthi i am sorry to say, i dont have target folder inside the the product folder within distribution.

Comment: Hi, what is the version, is it 1.0.0 ?

Comment: Hi, can you run "mvn clean install" from the modules/distribution folder and see. if the build was done correctly there should be an target folder :).

Comment: Hi, Pulasthi i tried it but i got the fallowing error:[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-2:attached (pre_dist) on project wso2am: Failed to create assembly: Error creating
assembly archive null: You must set at least one file. -> [Help 1]

Comment: Hi, It seems that you are getting build errors. when you ran "mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dproduct=apimgt" did it built successfully?. to correctly build you should first built orbit then kernel and the then platform. if you did build orbit and kernal try running "mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true" from products/apimgt/1.0.0 folder :).

Comment: Hi Pulasthi, I built from products/apimgt/1.0.0 it was successfull. Now i am able to see target folder inside product and i am able to see the portal up, thanks a lot for your constant and quick support :):)